# Nginx serve landing page seperate from VueJS app

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nginx, server

I am trying to serve my landing page and my Vuejs app separately.

Below is Nginx config for serving my VueJS app and it's working fine. How can I configure it to serve my landing page from "/" and my VueJS app from "/app"?

```
server {
  listen $PORT;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }

  location ~ ^/(?:wizard_question|wizard_submit) {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5050;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_redirect      default;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your config already should serve the static content located in `/usr/share/nginx/html`, change this path to directory where your landing page is located.

Comment: inside /usr/share/nginx/html is the /dist and index.html from the VueJS app. The landing page is under /nginx/landing

Comment: You should rewrite all routes of your application and append the `/app` prefix to them, and make your assets URIs either relative or started with the `/app` prefix too. Are you able to do it?

Comment: yes, so I prepend all my routes now to /app. Now how do I configure nginx config above to handle this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you change your routes and assets paths, try the following config:

```
server {
  listen $PORT;

  index index.html index.html;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/landing;
  }

  location /app/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/;
    try_files $uri /app/index.html;
  }

  location ~ ^/(?:wizard_question|wizard_submit) {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5050;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_redirect      default;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, modified a few things but this worked out just great! Thanks!